# how to create flask api without a model

Tags: flask

I'm trying to put together a small Flask service, which should serve up an AngularJS app, and then, proxy any subsequent requests between this angular app and a protected resource behind a firewall.

In this scenario, the flask app will not have any models of its own. When responding to requests, it will need to parse the requested URL, and then use urllib2 to make an API call to a protected resource.

What would be the correct syntax for the API Manager to create_api, given, that such API is not going to be associated with any model?

Comment: What frame work are you using? Flask-Restless?

Comment: Yes, I am using Flask-Restless

Answer (score 0):

In the angular app, I did this api call:

```
$http.get('/signed_contracts')
```

And in the Flask controller I've handled this call in the following way:

```
@app.route('/signed_contracts')
def signed_contracts():
    url = "http://10.0.0.21:3748/api/pipeline"
    req =  urllib2.Request(url)
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    text = resp.read()
    contracts = text

    return contracts
```

This way, my Flask service is, essentially, stateless - it accepts a request from the angular front-end, makes an api call to a remote protected resource, and passes the result back to the front-end client.